# File named 'phishingurlrc' in .config directory

Tags: 18.04

I just noticed this file in my `~/.config`, but can't find any details on how it may have got there. It only contains 2 lines:

```
DataBaseState=[clipped]
RefreshDataBase=[clipped]
```

Appreciate any advice on what this file is, and whether I should leave it be.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a bit more context?

Answer (score 4):

It is a legitimate file created if you have used `kmail` on your system. If you don't use `kmail`, feel free to delete it. [This link](https://invent.kde.org/pim/messagelib/-/blob/master/webengineviewer/src/checkphishingurl/checkphishingurlutil.cpp#L23-41) mentions *phishingurlrc*.

[Here's someone's file](https://github.com/OriishiTakahiro/myconfs/blob/master/phishingurlrc) uploaded to GitHub:

```
[General]
DataBaseState=Cg0IARAGGAEiAzAwMTABEPyaAxoCGATU4Ug9
RefreshDataBase=1813.311s
```

You may also have `~/.local/share/phishingurl/malware.db` on your system. See https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/530672-Which-program-creates-local-share-phishingurl-malware-db

Comment: What a terrible name.